# Question about a theorem and proofs

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have a question about this theorem.

Let $m, n \in\mathbb{Z}$, $m$ odd and $n$ odd. Then it holds that $\exists k_1, k_2 \in\mathbb{Z}$, so that $m = 2k_1+1$ and $n = 2k_2+1$.

This gives us:

- $$m+n = (2k_1+1)+(2k_2+1)$$
- $$\to m+n = 2(k_1+k_2+1)$$
- $$\to m+n = 2l,\quad l = k_1+k_2+1, \quad l\in\mathbb{Z}$$
- The sum $m+n$ is even.

If they already write that there exists some integer $k_1$ and $k_2$, why do they need to repeat it later by writing "$m+n = 2l$, $l = k_1+k_2+1$, $l\in\mathbb{Z}$"?

Then I wonder about this formulation of the same theorem:

- If $m$ and $n$ are odd integers, then $m + n$ is even.
- For all integers $m$ and $n$, if $m$ and $n$ are odd, then $m + n$ is even.
- $$(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{Z})((m \text{ odd} \land n \text{ odd})\to m+n \text{ even}))$$
- $m$ odd integers $\land$ $n$ odd integers $\to$ $m+n$ even

I've tried to find something on Google, but I can't find anything about these so-called "implicit universal statements" as well as "explicit universal statements".

How do you know which is which, and what is meant by implicit and explicit statements, and whether they are universal or not? I have heard my teacher say that $\implies$ is a universal implication, and that $\to$ is not.

Do we mean that "implicit" means not mentioning any specific integer? But why is this one:

> $m$ odd integers $\land$ $n$ odd integers $\implies$ $m+n$ even

an explicit universal statement, and

> If $m$ and $n$ are odd integers, then $m + n$ is even.

an implicit universal claim?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser The time it takes to format, I could plow through one whole chapter of my textbook. As long as I can make myself understood by people, I don't see the issue.

Comment: @Ericleast992 The user who formatted your post for you did it in less than 10 minutes.  In all likelihood it took about a minute.  The issue is that you're making a contribution to this site in order to help future readers.  We hope you make that contribution as good as possible, that's all.

Comment: @rschwieb I strongly disagree that formality is a prerequisite to being understood properly.

Comment: No. But legibility is. Don't worry too much, MathJax is not hard to pick up. I might say that the title should be more descriptive: clicking on this post, I had absolutely no idea what I was going to find.

Comment: To answer your first question, to claim $m+n=2l$ you need to define the symbol $l$. That is all

Comment: I downvoted for the attitude expressed by "the time it takes to format, I could plow through one whole chapter of my textbook". (1) If you expect people to help you, you should do them the respect of adhering to the standards of the community. Here, the standard is that you format mathematics using MathJax. (2) In the long run, leaning how to format math with LaTeX/MathJax will be much more valuable to you "plowing through" a chapter of a textbook. One of the keys to success in math is learning to write and read *very slowly* and *carefully*, as well as learning how to communicate clearly.

Comment: @Ericleast992 Perhaps at a site where you've paid a subscription fee you can try to demand things on your terms, but this isn't that, it's a community project.  A modicum of open-mindedness for cooperation is essential.  I think you'll find that most requests (such as the suggestion to check out formatting tips) are not very demanding.  Such suggestions are made with the intention of getting your post more positive attention and better answers.  Anyhow, your post looks good now. Just keep in mind that there are guidelines out there that everyone is answerable to, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

To answer you first question you may want to recall the definition of an even number: an intenger $z$ is even if there exists some integer $l$ such that $z = 2l$. The proof just shows that for $z=m+n$ we have $l=k_1+k_2+1$. It is not strictly necessary too use the label $l$ for the integer $k_1+k_2+1$ but it makes the proof cleaner and the conclusion looks more like the definition.

To your other question. An implicit universal statement is a universal statement in which we don't explicitly say or write "every". For instance, if you say "the square of a real number is positive", you mean the same as "for every real number, its square is positive". This is more a matter of language than of logic.

Also, when you say that $n$ is an odd integer you are already quantifying it (but with words). So saying "If $n$ is an odd integer..." is precisely the same as saying "$\forall n\in \mathrm{Odd}$...", where $\mathrm{Odd}$ is the set of odd integers. Since the odd integers are a subset of the integers, you can simply quantify explicitly over the integers  ($\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$..) and then restrict to the subset (...if $n$ is odd...).

Comment: I have a question since this one was left unanswered I think: ”If they already write that there exists some integer 1 k 1  and 2 k 2 , why do they need to repeat it later by writing "+=2 m + n = 2 l , =1+2+1 l = k 1 + k 2 + 1 , ∈ℤ l ∈ Z"?”

Comment: @Ericleast992 I explain it in the answer: "It is not strictly necessary too use the label $l$ for the integer $k1+k2+1$ but it makes the proof cleaner and the conclusion looks more like the definition." It makes the proof more readable as a result.